# Authentication in xmpp - iOS

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

can we call authentication mechanism any where out of the below function?

```
- (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender
```

I tried to authenticate a user from other controllers but it returns an error. I'm using xmpp framework to send an IQ to register a user. When xmpp stream is connected it authenticates a user anonymously which enables me to send an IQ to register a user and user gets registered. However, when it gets registered I want to authenticate the registered user again but this time not anonymously so that it can send its presence and can become online with his own name. Please suggest a solution, Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/ it's include sample code. It may help and still do you have any issue then comment here i will try to give my best.

Comment: hi Yashesh, Thanks for your reply. I'm using the above framework that you have mentioned. It contains the function to check if it supports the authentication mechanism.  This function has an if statement: "if (state >= STATE_XMPP_POST_NEGOTIATION)" and the value of "state" is never greater than 2 whenever it is called and therefore if condition never gets executed. However when authentication method is called from "- (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender" in app delegate "state" value is 12 and it then works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to reuse existing xmpp connection after registration, you should start a new connection.

Comment: Yes true, I'm registering a user by sending an IQ once its authenticated anonymously. When I receive a response of my IQ in "- (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq" current xmpp stream is disconnected and [self connect] is called again so that it starts a new connection and this time authenticate the user using its credentials and not anonymously.

Comment: So, you should save username and password and check in `xmppDidConnect` handler: if you already have username and password then send `authenticateWithPassword:...`, or send registration IQ if none.

Comment: Anyway, your "business logic" is wrong, you should not register user every time you want to connect, in most cases registration is separate  action and it should not be mixed with main connection flow.

Comment: Thanks vitalyster, but that is my question. User never gets registered every time. When user click login then it sends "authenticate with password" only. It only gets register if user clicks the registration button but when it registers anonymously and I'm able to send an IQ it then disconnects by calling [self disconnect] and [self connect] is called again and this time it won't authenticate anonymously and will authenticate using the password given by the user during registration.

Comment: Authenticatewithpassword is called but I never gets a response in "- (void)xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender" and therefore it doesn't go online as [self goOnline] is present in the function "- (void)xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender". First time when it authenticates anonymously "- (void)xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender" is invoked and anonymous user goes online but when it disconnects and for the second time when it authenticates using the password "- (void)xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender" is never invoked. Please help.

Comment: maybe authentication is failed, you can check `error` param and `- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didNotAuthenticate:(NSXMLElement *)error;`

Comment: "- (void)xmppStreamDidNotAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender {
    //authentication unsuccessful.
    NSLog(@"authentication unsuccessful");
}" I have put a break point here but this function is never called.

Comment: I used "- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didNotAuthenticate:(NSXMLElement *)error{}" that you sent above and it did work. Thanks a lot. But now how will I know the exact error?

Comment: <failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><not-authorized/></failure>. This is what I'm getting in error log :(

Comment: It means you sent wrong username and/or password, check it twice before sending

Comment: Hi @MugheesMusaddiq, do you have a handler to wait for authentication to be processed before allowing user to access? Because the waiting time between `- (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender` and `- (void)xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender` is noticeably long.

Comment: @KeithOYS How much time is it taking? It hardly takes 2-3 seconds to authenticate. I don't know if there is any handler to wait for authentication to be processed before allowing user to access. However, you can use `- (void)xmppStreamDidNotAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender` to check if it doesn't authenticates.